# Substring in unix ksh88

Tags: unix, ksh

Its a simple question but giving too much trouble to workaround.
All solutions mentioned works with ksh99. But unfortunately i use ksh88 and i am unable to get substring from a string.

I am trying to get year part of the string. but i am getting an error. The cut syntax seems fine. also the assignment to the variable.

```
cut: The list arguments following the c option are not correct.
```

Here is the statement used.

```
typeset -i dt_year=`echo 201610118 | cut -c1-4`
```

Comment: It's hard to imagine that the code as posted would fail. Does the `cut` command work stand-alone? See if you can craft an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As you're stuck with ksh88, I'm guessing you're using a old-line Unix variant, HP, or AIX, both known for their quirky implementations. Did you check `man cut` to see that `c` actually means character;-) ? Maybe add a tag for your OS. (And I'm sure you mean ksh95. While new kshs where coming out until 2 yrs ago, they are all still classed as ksh95. Finally, did you look for `/usr/xpg4/bin/ksh` or some other dir?) Good luck.

Comment: Try `echo 201610118 | cut -c1-4`. When that works, try your command without `typeset -i`. Also try `typeset -i dt_year="2016"`. Combine these tests for pinpointing your problem.

Comment: @shellter You do mean `ksh93`, right?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth : Doah! Yep, ksh93. (I can't blame being up early/late for that!). Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

I would in ksh88 separate your line in:

```
typeset -i dt_year=0

dt_year=`echo "201610118" | cut -c1-4`
```

You can also try to leave out the `cut -c-4`

And check with alias if `cut` is aliased.